# What is wrong with my rose bushes?

Tags: diagnosis, roses

I have a rose bush in the front yard and several in the back yard which just started exhibiting the issues show in the pictures. I live in Missouri and these bushes have been healthy until this. [image: Pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

Comment: I don't think that explains the spots on the leaves though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sawfly larvae is your problem with the white marks.  Also, you need to get those flowers off your shrubs, do not allow them to go to seed, this reduces the vigor and the plant's own defenses.[roses sawfly larvae](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/Portals/0/Gardening/Gardening%20Help/images/Pests/Pest2477.jpg)

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean shrubs?

Comment: Roses are shrubs.  Anything with woody stems is either a shrub or a tree; also called woody perennials.